# CSS: Align div to center when viewport's large enough, otherwise to negative margin?

Tags: css, html, alignment, margin

Let's assume the following html markup:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

I would like the inner div to be centered in its parent (*container*) while if there is not enough space in the viewport, it should gradually go to negative left margin upto -XY px.

The situation is:
I have a container div that always has a plain background. In this div I have another div that has a ribbon as a background and contains the navigation. If the viewport is wide enough, I want to show everything (=from the inner div) centered on the page. So far no problem by setting `margin: 0 auto` to the inner. However, when the viewport is less than the ribbon's width, I would like to "cut off" the ribbon on the left side (logically, on the right it is automatic) to the point where it "bends", that's the point where the buttons of the navigation begin (169px from left). I have come up with this:

```
#container {
    height: 240px;
    position: relative;
    background: url("../images/top_noise_bg.png") top left repeat #222;
    margin-left: -169px;
    margin-right: -169px;
}
```

The margin works as intended when the viewport is large enough. When it is too small, the left side works just right, however the negative right margin cuts the *top_noise* background off on the right side when I scroll there. Also it creates another undesired effect: the page will always have horizontal scrollbars. Any advices how to solve this? Thank you!

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/CrG68/) -> resize the area to very small, then scroll to right of the red div.

Comment: It would be helpful to create a codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: @Cam Yes, sorry, added.

Comment: Are you thinking of using js to do this??

Comment: @Cam I wasn't as I assumed there is some handy CSS solution available. If no CSS solution comes up I guess I will go with js (not much of a problem) but I am really interested in CSS.

Comment: [Is this what you're looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/CrG68/1/)

Comment: @ZachSaucier Awesome, exactly! I assume this wouldn't work in IE8, would it? What about the scrollbars, is it possible to solve that?

Comment: @Cam Agreed, but there is no pure CSS way to do that

Comment: @ZachSaucier no your way works because the div is actually fixed. If it was responsive that would be an issue.

Comment: @Fygo this will solve your scrollbar issue. http://jsfiddle.net/CrG68/2/

Comment: @Fygo I think I understand what you're trying to do: to start the scrollbar in the middle of the content. If so it is impossible to do without javascript. This is a bad idea anyway, you should use `@media` queries to make your page responsive by resizing or reformatting any necessary parts, not by using this poor work around

Comment: @ZachSaucier No, I mean - the horizontal scrollbar should not be visible when all the inner div fits the container. However, it is, which I assume is caused by the margin on the right. I guess I will indeed have to go for a js solution.